# The number of solutions to $\frac{1}x+\frac{1}y+\frac{1}z=\frac{3}n,x,y,z\in\mathbb N$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Denote 
$$g(n)=\{\{x,y,z\}\mid \frac{1}x+\frac{1}y+\frac{1}z=\frac{3}n,x,y,z\in\mathbb N\},$$
$$h(n)=\{\{x,y,z\}\mid \frac{1}x+\frac{1}y+\frac{1}z=\frac{3}n,1\leq x\leq y\leq z,x,y,z\in\mathbb N\},$$
 let $f(n)=|g(n)|$ be the number of members of $g(n)$.

For example, $h(3)=\{\{2,3,6\},\{2,4,4\},\{3,3,3\}\},f(3)=6+3+1=10.$

Since $\{n,n,n\}$ is a solution to $\frac{1}x+\frac{1}y+\frac{1}z=\frac{3}n$, it's easy to see that $f(k)\equiv 1\pmod 3,\forall k\in \mathbb N.$

> ***Question:*** I find that 
>   $$f(3k)\equiv 0,f(4k+2)\equiv 0,f(6k\pm1)\equiv1 \pmod 2,\forall k\in \mathbb N.$$
>   I wonder how to prove them?

Edit: I find that $f(n)$ has the same parity to the number of solutions to $\frac{1}x+\frac{2}y=\frac{3}n,$ I think I have got it now.

Comment: @Calvin Lin If not, I will type $\{2,3,6\}$ $6$ times and $\{2,4,4\}$ $3$ times in my example, such as $\{2,3,6\},\{2,6,3\},\{3,2,6\}\dots$

Comment: Ah I see. This makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: If you have an answer, you are encouraged to post it and accept it.  That way others can see it and your question doesn't stay in the still open queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I already know how to prove them, I write a proof here now.

It's easy to see that in $h(n)$,

(1)if $x,y,z$ are distinct, then $x,y,z$ add $6$ to $f(n)$,

(2)if just two of them are equal, add $3$ to $f(n)$,

(3)if $x=y=z$, then they add $1$ to $f(n)$.

Since $6$ is even, case (1) didn't change the parity of $f(n)$. Hence $f(n)$ has the same parity of the number of solutions to $\frac{1}x+\frac{2}y=\frac{3}n.$ This is $(3x-n)(3y-2n)=2n^2,$ let $r(n)$ be the number of solutions to this equation.

If $n=3m,$ then $(x-m)(y-2m)=2m^2,$ hence $f(n)\equiv r(n)=d(2m^2)\equiv 0\pmod 2.$

If $n=6m+1$, then $3x-n=a,3y-2n=b,$
$$f(n)\equiv r(n)=\sum_{\substack{ab=2n^2\\a\equiv -n\equiv 2\pmod 3\\b\equiv -2n\equiv 1\pmod 3}}1=\frac{1}2d(2n^2)=d(n^2)\equiv 1\pmod 2.$$
The same to $n=6m-1.$

If $n=4m+2,$ then if $3\mid n$, we get $2\mid f(n),$ too. If $3\not \mid n$, then  $2n^2\equiv -1\pmod3,f(n)\equiv r(n)=\dfrac{1}2d(2n^2)=2d((2m+1)^2)\equiv 0\pmod 2.$

Now we get a little more: 
$$f(n) \equiv
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}2d(2n^2),  & 3\not\mid n \\
0, & 3\mid n \\
\end{cases} \pmod 2 $$